# Fix .net core error when pulling from git repo

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

So I made a .net core web api project and pushed it to a git repo. After pulling down the repo and attempting to run the IIS express server locally, I'm getting the error

> Unable to run your project. The "RunCommand" property is not defined.

If I create a new web api project on this computer, it works fine. So it's only the project that I've pulled from git that won't work. Is there some command I need to run to make it...I don't know, update for this computer?

I've done almost nothing to this project. I added one new controller and that's it. Everything else is the default project settings.

The exact project is:
Templates -> .NET Core -> ASP.Net Core Web Application

.NET Framework 4.5.2

Edit: I've compared the new project I created with the one I cloned and everything looks the same. So I'm baffled.

Comment: can you attach the link to github project ?

Comment: So, the pull from GitHub worked, but the application will not run? Your questions makes it seem like the issue is pulling the code down. Did you restore all NuGet packages in the project on the destination machine after pulling the code?

Comment: I can't link it. It's a private repo. I also edited the question for clarity. I can pull the repo fine. It's just running the project once it's cloned is the issue.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to check in .vs folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `OutputType` of the project is set to `Exe` and that the project file starts with `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`.

Both are important to give VS:

- The command to run when  executing the project
- Turn on the capabilities to generate and use a `Properties/launchSettings.json` file.

If your app doesn't launch, i suggest deleting a `Web.config` file (if exists) and `Properties/launchSettings.json`, then re-open the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to delete the

bin, obj, and .vs directories.

I just need to ignore those directories with gitignore and I won't have this issue anymore.